# Call backbone model function in view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a simple function in my model that should return true if the priority is 100

```
class App.Models.Publication extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/api/publications'

  isIncredible: ->
    @get('priority') is 100
```

In the view I wanna call the function, but I can't

```
class App.Views.PublicationShow extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'article'
  className: 'offer'
  template: JST['publications/show']

  render: =>
    if @model.isIncredible()
      $(@el).addClass('incredible').html(@template(publication: @model))
    else
      $(@el).html(@template(publication: @model))
    @modalEvent()
    this
```

I get: `TypeError: this.model.isIncredible is not a function`

Just as a note I'm using coffescript

Comment: Have you double checked (using debugger) that the model is of the correct type?

Comment: How do you instantiate `App.Views.PublicationShow`?

Comment: At the beginning of the render method of the view, log in the console @model. It should be pretty clear what's wrong.

Comment: I tried debugging it's not pretty clear what's wrong.
I can do the if directly on the view: `if @model.get('priority') is 100` and it works, but inspecting the model it just doesn't have the `isIncredible`function

Comment: @muistooshort sorry I don't know where that is, I'm working on someone elses code, is it in the router? or in the backbone app initializer?

Comment: Probably a router, you can always grep the whole source for `new.*PublicationShow` if all else fails. Could someone be sending in a plain `Backbone.Model` where they should be using a `Publication`?

Comment: @muistooshort this is where I found the `new.*PublicationShow` http://pastebin.com/k4eECf58 line 33, I see what is being passed is the `publication` from `@collection.models` when appending a new one

Comment: You need to find where the model `App.Models.Publication` is being created. Search for that. Or, look at the collection `model` property (as it should be set to the `Publication` class [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model)). If the collection being used in your `PublicationIndex` class doesn't have the model assigned, it will create plain-old-Models, rather than a typed model like you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the model in the view by either 1) setting it in the initialize function of the view

```
class App.Views.PublicationShow extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'article'
  className: 'offer'
  template: JST['publications/show']

  initialize: ->
      @model = new App.Models.Publication()

  render: =>
    if @model.isIncredible()
      $(@el).addClass('incredible').html(@template(publication: @model))
    else
      $(@el).html(@template(publication: @model))
    @modalEvent()
    this
```

or 2) pass in the model instance as argument to the view when instanciating it

```
pubModel = new App.Models.Publication(/*...*/)
pubShow = new App.Views.PublicationShow(model: pubModel)
```